# Cucumber and Clearance: current_user in steps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, cucumber, integration-testing, clearance

What I what to accomplish is to use (rely on) `current_user` method while defining Cucumber steps. I'm using Clearance in my project.

First of all I tried to use `sign_in` but it didn't work (I guess Cucumber World doesn't know about Clearance methods...).

So how do I make Cuckes recognize `current_user` and `sign_in`/`sign_out` methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Cucumber features should be driving your application through the public user interface.  Something like:

```
Given /^I am signed in as "([^\"]*)"%/ do |username|
  visit 'sign_in'
  fill_in 'Username', :with => username
  click 'Sign In'
end
```

Since the `current_user` method isn't available to the browser, you shouldn't be using it in your spec.

You could fake it in your steps by storing `@current_user` in the above step and then providing an attribute reader for it.

Comment: After 9 months I realized how to cucke it right. Now understand why your answer was correct back in a day.

Comment: It's still frustrating though. Because `current_user` is `nil` even on the server side, not just the browser side.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the idea that every acceptance test (cucumber or otherwise) must exercise the login logic. Luckily, if you agree, Clearance has added a [back door](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/faster-tests-sign-in-through-the-back-door) in tests that lets you skip the sign in steps.

```
user = create(:user)
visit posts_path(as: user)
```

Now you can leave your login-related features driving the login ui as a user would and skip that for features that aren't directly related to logging in.